# SSL Mutual Authentication on Linux

Tags: ssl, mutual-authentication

It must be something really simple but right now I am not getting anywhere with this (I am not a network geek but a programmer).

We are trying to secure web services created between our server and a vendor. Our vendor is asking to send them the public key for an SSL certificate to secure requests and responses in our web services.

**What I did**

I forwarded the following to our hosting provider but they only provide SSL certificate for websites and didn't give any clear clue to what to do next.

- Create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) with any CN
- Have CSR signed from CA
- Merge the signed cert file with the CSR to create the actual
  certificate
- Extract the public and private certificates

**What I need**

All I need simple set of instructions to what I should do or where can I get/purchase this certificate.

Thanks,

Comment: "Merge the signed cert file with the CSR to create the actual certificate": no. Once the certificate is issued from the content in the CSR, the CSR can be discarded. You should not merge it with the certificate file. Also there are no "private certificates".  A certificate is basically a public key and some metadata and a signature over all of that. The corresponding private part is just a private key.

Comment: "All I need simple set of instructions to what I should do or where can I get/purchase this certificate." this is unfortunately offtopic for a website dedicated to programming.

Comment: I have generated CSR. Can you suggest which CA can issue client certificate? I have looked symantec, Digicert but couldn't find any option.

Comment: Any CA can. They may ask you for the CSR or let you enter all the details on their website instead. See this documentation that gives you link to 5 CAs documentation on CSR: https://www.sslshopper.com/what-is-a-csr-certificate-signing-request.html